# Decoding Bitmap stream failed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to work my through *"Sam's Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours"* and have become stuck in hour 12. The problem appears to be in this section:

```
private Drawable getQuestionImageDrawable(int questionNumber) {
    Drawable image;
    URL imageUrl;

    try {
        // Create a Drawable by decoding a stream from a remote URL
        imageUrl = new URL(getQuestionImageUrl(questionNumber));
        InputStream stream = imageUrl.openStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Decoding Bitmap stream failed");
        image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noquestion);
    }
    return image;
}
```

The `questionNumber` and `getQuestionImageUrl()` have been tested and are returning what I believe are the correct values(1 and `http://www.perlgurl.org/Android/BeenThereDoneThat/Questions/q1.png`).  There is an image at that url, but I always get the exception. I have tried several variations but when none of them worked I went back to this code from the book.  What am I doing wrong here?

I'm new to java and android, so I'm probably missing something simple.  I have had many other problems with the code in the book and the updated code from the website (all of which have been solved either here or with `developer.android.com`). This is my first question, so if I failed to provide any information please let me know.

Comment: Make sure you haven't forgotten to add INTERNET permission to your manifest file.

Comment: Thank you Egor! I had not added the INTERNET permission, and looking back through the book I don't see anywhere that it tells me to.  So far http://developer.android.com/training/index.html has been a much better learning tool than this book.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Got to say it's refreshing to see someone learning in a structured way and taking care and time to construct a good question.  For future reference, although not needed in this case, a question concerning an exception should usually include the relevant segment of the logcat output.  +1 to help you on your journey and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following and it might work:

```
private Drawable getQuestionImageDrawable(int questionNumber) {
Drawable image;
URL imageUrl;

try {
    // Create a Drawable by decoding a stream from a remote URL
    imageUrl = new URL(getQuestionImageUrl(questionNumber));
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Decoding Bitmap stream failed");
    image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noquestion);
}
return image;
}
```

Make sure you do this kind of heavy operations in a background thread insteaad of the main one and had INERNET permission to your application's manifest.
Let me know about your progress.

Comment: Egor got to it first, but the lack of INTERNET permission was the problem. Thanks also for the helpful demonstration.

Comment: UPDATE: this solution works perfectly in the emulator, but I still get the exception when testing on a device.  I'm doing more testing now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the exception is because you are making a network connection form the app ui thread. That works on older Android versions but not in the newer.
Take a look to [Android network operation section](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html).

The main thing to do is use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thank you. Egor turned out to have the immediate solution in the comments above, but your information is also useful.  I haven't gotten to multi-threading yet, but now I certainly see how useful it can be.